# MongooseIM keeps throwing FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE after server restart

Tags: erlang, mongoose-im

I am testing MongooseIM v.5.0.0 for my project.
I download the deb file for Ubuntu Xenial from this [link](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/)
And I deployed it under Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial AMD in VM.
I haven't customized its config files and just simply run it. My problem is: after restarting my VM a few times, the MongooseIM doesn't want to start and throws an error like below

```
root@ubuntu:~# mongooseimctl foreground
Root: /usr/lib/mongooseim
Exec: /usr/lib/mongooseim/erts-12.1/bin/erlexec -noshell -noinput +Bd -boot 
/usr/lib/mongooseim/releases/5.0.0/start -embedded -config /etc/mongooseim/app.config - 
args_file /etc/mongooseim/vm.args -args_file /etc/mongooseim/vm.dist.args -- foreground
fips.c(139): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE
/usr/bin/mongooseimctl: line 165:   856 Aborted                 
"$RUNNER_SCRIPT_DIR"/mongooseim foreground
```

I search for this error, but none seems to answer my problem.
Can anybody help me?